# How to do it in rails way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

newbie question.

To query on my custom database(i used mysql database instead of sqlite3).
According to rails guides, through rails Models it is efficient and easy to access data from my database.

But i did this way(i know its not the actual rails way) used a long query to return me some objects, and need suggestions to do it in rails way(I want my controller just call a model to return objects not do it by itself).

in my controller.

```
def near
      begin
        @lat = params[:lat]
        @lon = params[:lon]
        @near_ids = []

        def get_id(dist_var) 
          @near_ids = Bank.find_by_sql("SELECT id FROM(SELECT al.id,(3959 * acos(cos(radians(#{@lat})) * cos(radians(y(ppt))) * cos(radians(x(ppt)) - radians(#{@lon})) +sin(radians(#{@lat})) * sin(radians(y(ppt))))) AS distance FROM db1.tbl1 gf,db2.tbl1 al WHERE gf.object_type = 256 AND al.c_id = 10 AND gf.object_id = al.wp_id HAVING distance < #{dist_var}) S ORDER BY S.distance; ")  
          puts 'Total id :'+@near_ids.length.to_s
          puts 'distance :'+dist_var.to_s
        end

      get_id(dist = 1)

        while(@near_ids.length < 10)
          dist +=5
          get_id(dist)
        end

          @banks = []
          @near_ids.each do |bank|
            @banks << Store.find_by_id(bank["id"])
          end
          @user = @banks.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10 )
          rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
          render json: 'Not found', status: 404
      end
    end
```

And this is my Bank Model

```
class Bank < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'table1'
    has_many :branch, :foreign_key => 'tbl1_id'
end
```

And in my Branch model i used `belongs_to :Bank` using a foreign key.

Comment: Get a book on rails, maybe? Google for Agile Web Development with Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several concerns in your code, but let me try to wrap them up:

### Controller

How is the controller called? As you paginate through stores I assume it is the `StoresController`. In *Rails Way* we would expect a `StoresController` to perform actions on `Stores` models.

Also, in a more *RESTful* way, you would probably not define a function `near`, but rather a function `index` which lists all `Stores` and this list can be sorted by providing the `lat` and `lng` params.

### Models

It is unclear to me, why you do `Store.find_by_id(bank["id"])`. In normal scenarios such a call makes no sense, as a `bank_id` only *identifies* a `Bank` and not a `Store`. So I assume you are looking for some relations between `Bank` and `Store` model which you would achieve by adding a `bank_id` field to your `stores` Table and define the `Store` model as:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :bank
end
```

### Query

As previous answeres claimed, you would better go with so called *scopes* to put your query into the model and not the controller. But for your specific usecase I would recommend to have a look at the [geokit-rails gem](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails) which would allow you to do something like:

```
Store.by_distance(origin: [params[:lat],params[:lng]])
```

In order to use it you have to define your `Store` model to `acts_as_mappable` like this:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord:Base

 acts_as_mappable :through => :bank                

end
```

And of course you need the `lat` and `lng` fields defined in your `banks` table.

(Unfortunately the README of the geokit-rails gem is way out of date so you have to fiddle a bit to get it right)

### pagination

I think it is an error to write

@user = @stores.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10 )

With above query code you should instead write

@stores = Store.by_distance(origin: [params[:lat],params[:lng]]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)

### Error handling

It is unlikely that you will get an ActiveRecord::NotFound Exception, as these are usually only thrown when you use `find`-lookups on specific `id`. When you want to throw such an exception, you would to something like:

```
raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if @stores.empty?
```

at the bottom of your method.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to correct:

--

**SQLite3**

This is not the "rails way" - it is just the default db type shipped with Rails. They included it because it doesn't rely on any external database server to operate (keeping the system self-contained)

You're well within your liberty to use Mysql, or even PostgreSQL etc

--

**MVC**

I don't understand what your problem is exactly, but I'd recommend reading up about the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

[image]

This basically means you need to consider your system from the perspective of using your controller pulling specific data *from the model*, the model communicating with the data store, and the view showing the called data

Your controller contains direct SQL - a big no-no for MVC, as it will just lead to [flying spaghetti monster code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). You'll be better doing this:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
    def action
        @model = Model.your_class_method_or_scope
    end
end

#app/models/model.rb
Class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.your_class_method
        where("your query here")
    end
end
```

Finally, you really need to be specific on SO, in order to gain a specific answer. I don't know what your problem is directly

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a way to rewrite your MySQL-query the rails way? As this is not a common usecase, ActiveRecord doesn't provide a simple method for doing a geographical search. You need to rely on raw MySQL syntax.

Maybe the [MySQL-manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html) about spatial data will help you to improve your coordinates-search.